# Why does Formula Auditing | Trace function becomedisabled

Tags: excel, excel-2010

TL;DR: **Why/How does a workbook suddenly have Trace Auditing disabled (not protected)? What causes Excel to activate this behavior?**

I was working on an Excel spreadsheet that I had created a while back and wanted to use the Formula Auditing "Trace Precedent" functionality. To my surprise it was grayed out. Everything else worked fine except that feature. Neither the workbook nor the worksheet were protected.

Searching the web I was able to quickly find a solution:

```
File Menu>Options>Advanced>Display Options for this workbook>For Objects shown: select **"all"**
```

I want to know how to prevent this from popping up as an issue for employees who use my templates. Or what triggers it. I certainly didn't set this option in Excel on purpose.

Comment: Might have more luck asking here http://superuser.com/

Comment: you may be right. i'll post it on superuser and kill it here in a day or two if I see that it fits better over there. thanks!

Comment: _Or what triggers it._ You can toggle this option with Ctrl+6.

Comment: You mean CTRL+6 is the keyboard shortcut for this option?

Comment: Yes, at least in 2013.

Comment: Just tested it in 2010... works as well. So possibly I activated it by accident while using other keyboard short cuts... one possible answer. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered another reason why some of the formula auditing functions get disabled, even in worksheets where objects are being shown properly.

If I Ctrl+LeftClick more than one worksheet name tab at the bottom (which I do to include more than one sheet when I print), five of the six functions become greyed out, leaving only Show Formulas available. This peculiar behavior is present in Office 2010 for Windows and in Microsoft 365 (a.k.a. Office 365) for Windows.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then you have more than one worksheet activated. This actually grays out a whole range of functionality. Nevertheless, one more think to check if it happens to you. Thanks!